# How to turn off visibility of PictureBox which spawns on runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have been making game, where you get task to point every red/blue/green/yellow (random string `color`) object (PictureBoxes) which are being spawned at a start of a programme. I wanted to give PictureBoxes on click events to add or substract point (if the color is wrong with the one in task), but I also wanted to make clicked PictureBox disappear, and I don't really know how to make `goodshot` method know which PictureBox should disappear.

Goodshot method:

```
    private void goodshot(object sender, EventArgs e) //showing score
    {
        score++;
        scoring.Text = "Your score: " + score.ToString();
    }
```

Badshot method:

```
    private void badshot(object sender, EventArgs e) //showing score
    {
        score--;
        scoring.Text = "Your score: " + score.ToString();
    }
```

Creating PictureBoxes (there are else ifs for next colors (4 pictureboxes of every color)

```
PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            pb[i] = new PictureBox();
            if (i < 4)
            {
                pb[i].ImageLocation = redpaths[rng.Next(0, redpaths.Count - 1)];
                if(color == "red")
                {
                    pb[i].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(goodshot);
                }
                else if(color != "red")
                {
                    pb[i].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(badshot);
                }
            }
```

Comment: `((PictureBox)sender).Visible = false;`

Comment: `((Control)sender).Visible = false;` would work also.